# Unwanted grey border around the whole page

Tags: border

I notice that LaTeX is putting this grey border around the whole document page. How do you get rid of it?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=110pt,paperwidth=110pt,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

The grey border becomes part of the PDF document.

Comment: I believe it is an artifact of you pdf viewer.  I don't see it with Acrobat.

Comment: It's not in the PDF but just th difference between your non standard page size and your pdf viewer window, in xpdf, if I resize the viewer I see [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FZfH.png)